# Salt and managing .ssh/authorized_keys

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, salt-stack

Salt has a state module to manage `.ssh/authorized_keys`

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/develop/ref/states/all/salt.states.ssh_auth.html

I am not happy with it, since it combines code and data.

The state file is for me some kind of source code.

The ssh-key is for me data.

I don't want to combine both in one file.

Is there an other solution which separates code and data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't have to put them together in one file:

as per documentation: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.ssh_auth.html
you can use this method:

```
thatch:
  ssh_auth.present:
    - user: root
    - source: salt://ssh_keys/thatch.id_rsa.pub
    - config: /%h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

(contrary to the example in the documentation, i get an error if the config: value starts with a '%')

this keeps your keys in their appropriate files and only links them from your code by their filenames.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the [OpenSSH Formula](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/openssh-formula). `openssh/auth.sls` contains the code for a state that pulls all data from a pillar. In the root folder of the formula you find `pillar.example` that shows how to structure the data for a pillar.

Maybe this formula is a starting point for you.

Comment: For my eyes above formula is too complicated. I guess I prefer the state ssh_auth solution (see link in question).

Comment: Under the hood it is stil `ssh_auth` - but I agree that it might be overengineered in some scenarios. But it gives an idea how to configure it with pillars.